# How to implement Spring joint in Unity in the following manner?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need help regarding the spring joint. I am trying to make a game where when I drag back and release the gameObject should fly like in Angry Birds(but slightly different). The difference is, I don’t want the gameObject connected to the spring joint to move when i drag back. But when i release, the gameObject should move as if I did drag back.

Comment: If I understand correctly you don't even need a joint, you just want the object to fly when you release it right

Comment: Yes. You're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom spring. Spring forces are proportional to the distance from the resting point. So your force would be roughly

[pseudocode]

Force = Coefficient * (PositionOfMouse-PositionOfRestingPoint).magnitude

Rigidbodyofobject.addforce(result)

So to not move the object, calculate the mouse position relative to your object (probably need to raycast to a plane during mouse drag) calculate the force as if the mouse point was your object. But don’t actually move the object. Then apply the spring force to the actual object.

You might need to add some kind of coefficient in to modify the force, which would represent the tension of the spring.

Then you'd just need a script to turn off the spring a short time after releasing it ().

Comment: In real-world physics, spring forces are simply proportional to the distance to the resting point, not squared. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law

Comment: Ah! indeed. I got my equations mixed. Edited. thank you.

Comment: I can make the object fly when I drag it back and release it. But I dont want the object to move back when I drag back. Only my hand (or the mouse) should move back while I am dragging it.

Comment: Thank you @Adam. I will try it out!